# Mutual calls using camel rest-dsl

Tags: java, rest, apache-camel

We have two applications A and B configured with camel rest-dsl to listen for incoming calls. Triggering either of them works just fine. However, whenever we have A calling B and within this call B calling A as well, we get a HTTP 500 on A although B is not reporting any problem and the answer-processing on A is performed correctly.

We have narrowed it down to the following example:

System A:

```
from("timer://myTimer?period=600s")
    .process(new Processor() {...})
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("PUT"))
    .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/json"))
    .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
    .to("http4://localhost:8080/B/call")
    .end();

rest("/A").post("callResponse")
    .type(BResponse.class).consumes("application/json")
    .to("direct:handle");

from("direct:handle")
    .to("stream:out")
    .end();
```

System B

```
rest("/B").put("/call")
    .consumes("application/json")
    .type(BRequest.class)
    .to("direct:doB");

from("direct:doB")
    .process(requestToResponse)
    .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("POST"))
    .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/json"))
    .to("http4://localhost:8081/A/callResponse?bridgeEndpoint=true")
    .end();
}
```

Using a lot of logging within the processors and routes, we can see that the `BRequest` object is created correctly and we can also see it arriving undamaged at B. There we can trace it to be converted to a `BResponse` and this reponse is again correctly sent to A. We can see all stages of the A-Rest-Endpoint to be executed correctly and after a final `.to("stream:out)"` the exception is thrown at A with the message "HTTP operation failed invoking http://localhost:8081/B/call with status code 500".

Our original goal was to decouple the executions of A and B such that A calls B via rest, immediately gets an answer and continues working while B processes the request asynchronously. This obviously does not happen (A waits for B waits for A) and may be part of the problem?

Comment: Just guessing as I don't currently have time to test your example - It could be that `A` is expecting a synchronous response due to the ExchangePattern being `InOut`. So when setting the HTTP headers in `B` that could possibly mess with the response to the original call from `A`. You could try setting the ExchangePattern to `InOnly` right before calling `B` and see if that works.

Comment: I agree with @noMad17, it seems A at the end of .to("stream:out") is trying to send a reply back. If you have no need to for responses set exchangePattern to InOut and also use seda queues which are async unlike direct which are sync.

Comment: Hi @noMad17, we have tried setting the `Exchangepattern` to `InOnly`, both by specifying within the `RestDefinition` and by adding to the `.to`-parameters. It had no effect whatsoever. What we could also see is, that `B` receives the message as `InOut`, while `A` sends it as `InOnly`. We also tried adding a `.responseMessage()` part to the `RestDefinition`, also with no effect.

Comment: Hi @SoucianceEqdamRashti, we tried seda-queues as per your request and unfortunately, it didn't change anything. Do you know - by chance - a tutorial or code example, showing how this should be done?

Comment: @Jonathan, I will see if I can test this tonight and get back to you.

Comment: @Jonathan, I ran your code with small modification and it worked. I didn't get any error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took your code and removed parts which were not necessary and ran it and also included full logging with seda queue and exchange pattern set. I didn't get any errors and the logs were produced at the right places. Here is my code:

System A

```
public void configure() {
    restConfiguration().component("undertow").host("localhost").port(8080).bindingMode(RestBindingMode.auto);
    from("timer://myTimer?period=600s")
            .setBody(constant("{\"hello\":\"hello\"}"))
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("PUT"))
            .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/json"))

            .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
            .to("http4://localhost:8080/B/call")
            .end();

    rest("/A").post("callResponse")
            .consumes("application/json")
            .to("seda:handle");

    from("seda:handle")
    .to("log:com.mycompany.handle?showAll=true&multiline=true")
            .to("stream:out")
            .end();
}
```

System B

```
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        restConfiguration().component("undertow").host("localhost").port(8080).bindingMode(RestBindingMode.auto);
        rest("/B").put("/call")
                .consumes("application/json")
                //.type(BRequest.class)
                .to("direct:doB");

        from("direct:doB")
        .to("log:com.mycompany.B?showAll=true&multiline=true")
                .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)

                .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("POST"))
                .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/json"))
                .to("log:com.mycompany.BeforeSendingToA?showAll=true&multiline=true")
                .to("http4://localhost:8080/A/callResponse?bridgeEndpoint=true")
                .to("log:com.mycompany.AfterSendingToA?showAll=true&multiline=true")
                .end(); 
}
```

My logs when the camel app starts:

```
[ouciance.random.MainApp.main()] HttpComponent                  INFO  Created ClientConnectionManager org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager@4466f1ee
[ouciance.random.MainApp.main()] DefaultCamelContext            INFO  StreamCaching is not in use. If using streams then its recommended to enable stream caching. See more details at http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html
[ouciance.random.MainApp.main()] SedaEndpoint                   INFO  Endpoint seda://handle is using shared queue: seda://handle with size: 2147483647
[ouciance.random.MainApp.main()] DefaultCamelContext            INFO  Route: route3 started and consuming from: timer://myTimer?period=600s
[ouciance.random.MainApp.main()] DefaultCamelContext            INFO  Route: route4 started and consuming from: seda://handle
[ouciance.random.MainApp.main()] DefaultUndertowHost            INFO  Starting Undertow server on http://localhost:8080
[ouciance.random.MainApp.main()] xnio                           INFO  XNIO version 3.3.8.Final
[ouciance.random.MainApp.main()] nio                            INFO  XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.3.8.Final
[ouciance.random.MainApp.main()] DefaultCamelContext            INFO  Route: route1 started and consuming from: http://localhost:8080/A/callResponse?httpMethodRestrict=POST%2COPTIONS&matchOnUriPrefix=false
[ouciance.random.MainApp.main()] DefaultCamelContext            INFO  Route: route5 started and consuming from: direct://doB
[ouciance.random.MainApp.main()] DefaultCamelContext            INFO  Route: route2 started and consuming from: http://localhost:8080/B/call?httpMethodRestrict=PUT%2COPTIONS&matchOnUriPrefix=false
[ouciance.random.MainApp.main()] DefaultCamelContext            INFO  Total 5 routes, of which 5 are started
[ouciance.random.MainApp.main()] DefaultCamelContext            INFO  Apache Camel 2.20.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) started in 1.696 seconds
```

My logs when the timer kicks in and the requests/responses are sent.

```
[ouciance.random.MainApp.main()] DefaultCamelContext            INFO  Apache Camel 2.20.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) started in 1.696 seconds
[                 XNIO-1 task-1] B                              INFO  Exchange[
, Id: ID-moeed-Dator-1517066840557-0-3
, ExchangePattern: InOut
, Properties: {CamelCharsetName=ISO-8859-1, CamelCreatedTimestamp=Sat Jan 27 16:27:23 CET 2018, CamelExternalRedelivered=false, CamelMessageHistory=[DefaultMessageHistory[routeId=route2, node=route2], DefaultMessageHistory[routeId=route5, node=to4]], CamelToEndpoint=log://com.mycompany.B?multiline=true&showAll=true}
, Headers: {Accept-Encoding=gzip,deflate, breadcrumbId=ID-moeed-Dator-1517066840557-0-1, CamelHttpCharacterEncoding=ISO-8859-1, CamelHttpMethod=PUT, CamelHttpPath=, CamelHttpQuery=, CamelHttpRawQuery=, CamelHttpUri=/B/call, CamelHttpUrl=http://localhost:8080/B/call, Connection=Keep-Alive, Content-Length=23, Content-Type=application/json, firedTime=Sat Jan 27 16:27:23 CET 2018, Host=localhost:8080, User-Agent=Apache-HttpClient/4.5.3 (Java/1.8.0_71)}
, BodyType: String
, Body: {"hello":"hello"}
, Out: null: 
]
[                 XNIO-1 task-1] BeforeSendingToA               INFO  Exchange[
, Id: ID-moeed-Dator-1517066840557-0-3
, ExchangePattern: InOut
, Properties: {CamelCharsetName=ISO-8859-1, CamelCreatedTimestamp=Sat Jan 27 16:27:23 CET 2018, CamelExternalRedelivered=false, CamelMessageHistory=[DefaultMessageHistory[routeId=route2, node=route2], DefaultMessageHistory[routeId=route5, node=to4], DefaultMessageHistory[routeId=route5, node=marshal2], DefaultMessageHistory[routeId=route5, node=setHeader3], DefaultMessageHistory[routeId=route5, node=setHeader4], DefaultMessageHistory[routeId=route5, node=to5]], CamelToEndpoint=log://com.mycompany.BeforeSendingToA?multiline=true&showAll=true}
, Headers: {Accept-Encoding=gzip,deflate, breadcrumbId=ID-moeed-Dator-1517066840557-0-1, CamelHttpCharacterEncoding=ISO-8859-1, CamelHttpMethod=POST, CamelHttpPath=, CamelHttpQuery=, CamelHttpRawQuery=, CamelHttpUri=/B/call, CamelHttpUrl=http://localhost:8080/B/call, Connection=Keep-Alive, Content-Length=23, Content-Type=application/json, firedTime=Sat Jan 27 16:27:23 CET 2018, Host=localhost:8080, User-Agent=Apache-HttpClient/4.5.3 (Java/1.8.0_71)}
, BodyType: byte[]
, Body: "{\"hello\":\"hello\"}"
, Out: null: 
]
[l-1) thread #2 - seda://handle] handle                         INFO  Exchange[
, Id: ID-moeed-Dator-1517066840557-0-8
, ExchangePattern: InOut
, Properties: {CamelCharsetName=ISO-8859-1, CamelCorrelationId=ID-moeed-Dator-1517066840557-0-5, CamelCreatedTimestamp=Sat Jan 27 16:27:23 CET 2018, CamelExternalRedelivered=false, CamelMessageHistory=[DefaultMessageHistory[routeId=route1, node=route1], DefaultMessageHistory[routeId=route4, node=to2]], CamelToEndpoint=log://com.mycompany.handle?multiline=true&showAll=true}
, Headers: {Accept-Encoding=gzip,deflate, breadcrumbId=ID-moeed-Dator-1517066840557-0-1, CamelHttpCharacterEncoding=ISO-8859-1, CamelHttpMethod=POST, CamelHttpPath=, CamelHttpQuery=, CamelHttpRawQuery=, CamelHttpUri=/A/callResponse, CamelHttpUrl=http://localhost:8080/A/callResponse, Connection=Keep-Alive, Content-Length=23, Content-Type=application/json, firedTime=Sat Jan 27 16:27:23 CET 2018, Host=localhost:8080, User-Agent=Apache-HttpClient/4.5.3 (Java/1.8.0_71)}
, BodyType: String
, Body: {"hello":"hello"}
, Out: null: 
]
{"hello":"hello"}
[                 XNIO-1 task-1] AfterSendingToA                INFO  Exchange[
, Id: ID-moeed-Dator-1517066840557-0-3
, ExchangePattern: InOut
, Properties: {CamelCharsetName=UTF-8, CamelCreatedTimestamp=Sat Jan 27 16:27:23 CET 2018, CamelExternalRedelivered=false, CamelMessageHistory=[DefaultMessageHistory[routeId=route2, node=route2], DefaultMessageHistory[routeId=route5, node=to4], DefaultMessageHistory[routeId=route5, node=marshal2], DefaultMessageHistory[routeId=route5, node=setHeader3], DefaultMessageHistory[routeId=route5, node=setHeader4], DefaultMessageHistory[routeId=route5, node=to5], DefaultMessageHistory[routeId=route5, node=to6], DefaultMessageHistory[routeId=route5, node=to7]], CamelSkipGzipEncoding=true, CamelToEndpoint=log://com.mycompany.AfterSendingToA?multiline=true&showAll=true}
, Headers: {Accept-Encoding=gzip,deflate, breadcrumbId=ID-moeed-Dator-1517066840557-0-1, CamelHttpCharacterEncoding=ISO-8859-1, CamelHttpMethod=POST, CamelHttpPath=, CamelHttpQuery=, CamelHttpRawQuery=, CamelHttpResponseCode=200, CamelHttpResponseText=OK, CamelHttpUri=/B/call, CamelHttpUrl=http://localhost:8080/B/call, Connection=keep-alive, Content-Length=23, Content-Type=application/json, Date=Sat, 27 Jan 2018 15:27:23 GMT, firedTime=Sat Jan 27 16:27:23 CET 2018, User-Agent=Apache-HttpClient/4.5.3 (Java/1.8.0_71)}
, BodyType: org.apache.camel.converter.stream.CachedOutputStream.WrappedInputStream
, Body: [Body is instance of java.io.InputStream]
, Out: null: 
]
```

As you can see I don't get the http error which you could.

Comment: Hi, your solution works in our setting. We have determined the difference. Your code works, because it uses undertow. Changing to jetty/netty/restlet doesn't work. Same with our example. It purrs like a kitten, as soon as we switch to undertow. Any idea what this could be about?

Comment: Hmm, interesting observation. I can't think of a reason on top of my head but I will will test it with netty and restlet tonight and get back to you.